# How to save RecyclerView.Adapter's data during rotation?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have an adapter, which data consists of my classes AppData (with fields : String, String, Drawable). I implemented drag and drop feature in my recycler view , so I can change views position -> my adapters data changes(actually elements in List are swapped). 
But when my activity is killed/ device is rotated data is recreated and positions the order is lost.

I tried this:
implemented Parcelable in AppData and tried to save data in onSaveInstance(). But the size of data is to large to store it in Bundle.

How can I save this order?

**Thanks everyone for answers in advance!**

Comment: see [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html)

Comment: If the data is too large, you need a local data storage or stored in database. As your data struct only two strings, the drawable shouldn’t be saved as parcel. Try to use resource id or url in data, not binary bitmap.

Comment: @pskink As I understood viewmodel doesn't save instance and if I close my app all order wouldn't be saved

Comment: use [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) for that

Comment: @pskink Can you explain some details please? I should use model view + room? But how can room can help me?

Comment: @pskink so I just need to save all my entities into db? is in good to save drawable in db?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have your answer. But before that, try to use this adapter. It implement every thing you need for a recycler view. Make your life easier

https://github.com/CymChad/BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to persist all your data, store just the unique part of it. E.g. if your `AppData` class contains information about apps, it will probably contain the package name, which is sufficient for identifying your objects. It is sufficient to store the package name and the order in the list to be able to rebuild the list in the right order in the future.